# Is there a way in C# to access object properties in old, Pascal "with" keyword way?

Tags: c#, keyword, code-snippets

This is the Pascal sample I want to achieve in C#:

```
With myBook do
 Begin
  Title  := 'Some Book';
  Author := 'Victor John Saliba';
  ISBN   := '0-12-345678-9';
  Price  := 25.5;
 End;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you can find an explanation [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336816.aspx)

Excerpt:

> - **Small or non-existent readability benefits.** We thought the readability benefits were small or non-existent. I won't go as far as to say that the with statement makes code less readable, but some people probably would.
> - **Increased language complexity.** Adding a with statement would make the language more complex. For example, VB had to add new language syntax to address the potential ambiguity between a local variable (Text) and a property on the "with" target (.Text). Other ways of solving this problem also introduce language complexity. Another approach is to push a scope and make the property hide the local variable, but then there's no way to refer to the local without adding some escape syntax.
> - **C++ heritage.** C++ has never had a with statement, and the lack of such a statement is not generally thought to be a problem by C++ developers. Also, we didn't feel that other changes -- changes in the kind of code people are writing, changes in the platform, other changes in the language, etc. -- made with statements more necessary.

Answer (score 8):

Only when constructing.

```
var foo = new Foo
{
  Title = "lol",
  Author = "Som Gai",
  ISBWhatever = "111"
}
```

VB.NET has the 'with' keyword, but c# does not.

Comment: Note that this is only available in C# 3.0 and later.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to make new object.

Comment: There is no equivalent.  You can only do this kind of thing when initializing a new object.

Answer (score 2):

No there is not. It has been discussed before and most people don't want it.

It hurts readability, creates ambiguous situations, makes debugging harder and it's convenience is largely offset by IntelliSense.

To address your last comment, you can of course write:

```
myBook.Title = "Some Book";
...
```

Comment: Or it would be a case when C# would be like VB.NET and all the people who pretend they are too smart for VB.NET would be bummed.

Comment: But what's the huge difference to be able to set props when constructing, but unable to set them afterwards...?

Comment: ni5ni6, that last comment is about readonly or private fields, it has nothing to do with __With__.